Logging of cucumber steps takes a lot of time in automation execution
While I am running my serenity cucumber tests using mvn clen verify and all my tests gets execute it is taking around 2 to 3 hours to show the detailed summary of the features steps and then the serenity report gets execute
How can I skip this logging part so that I can reduce the execution time of my serenity report getting generated
pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.auto</groupId>
    <artifactId>automated-test-suite</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>automation-suite</name>
    <description>Automation project</description>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Central Maven repository</id>
            <name>Central Maven repository https</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <serenity.version>3.9.8</serenity.version>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.10.1</junit.jupiter.version>
        <junit.vintage.version>5.10.1</junit.vintage.version>
        <junit-platform-suite.version>1.10.1</junit-platform-suite.version>
        <cucumber-junit-platform-engine.version>7.15.0</cucumber-junit-platform-engine.version>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.11.0</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.surefire.plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
        <maven.failsafe.plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</maven.failsafe.plugin.version>
        <maven.exec.skip>true</maven.exec.skip>
        <tags/>
        <it.skip>true</it.skip>
        <app.profiles>dev</app.profiles>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <offset.hours>7</offset.hours>
        <offset.minutes>30</offset.minutes>
        <adjusted.timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</adjusted.timestamp>
        <app.profiles>dev</app.profiles>
    </properties>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>bintray-plugins</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Serenity Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber-junit-platform-engine.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform-suite.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>-->
        <!--            <version>1.19.6</version>-->
        <!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.50</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.22.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codoid.products</groupId>
            <artifactId>fillo</artifactId>
            <version>1.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.29</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>vaultReadJson</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>${maven.exec.skip}</skip>
                            <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                            <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
                            <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
                            <mainClass>com.auto.testautomation.common.YamlReader</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>run-spring-boot</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>mvn</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>spring-boot:run</argument>
                            </arguments>
                            <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}</workingDirectory>
                            <async>true</async>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.failsafe.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/RunnerTest.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <skip>${maven.exec.skip}</skip>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>serenity-single-page-report</artifactId>
                        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <!--                    <tags>${tags}</tags>-->
                    <reports>single-page-html</reports>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-zip</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${maven.exec.skip}</skip>
                    <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                    <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
                    <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
                    <mainClass>com.auto.common.fillo.ZipUtils</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("features")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "com.auto.testautomation.steps")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "io.cucumber.core.plugin.SerenityReporterParallel,pretty,timeline:build/test-results/timeline")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = FILTER_TAGS_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "")
public class RunnerTest {
    
}

